# Logstash-forwarder not working

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

I configured logstash forwarder and try to parse the log files.Hope I did all the steps correctly by referring logstash book.While running the logstash configuration file and logstash forwarder I'm not seeing any error, but the file parsing is not starting.

Here are my configuration details

```
1. cat /etc/logstash/central.conf
input {
lumberjack {
port => 6782
ssl_certificate => "/etc/logstash/server.crt"
ssl_key => "/etc/logstash/server.key"
type => "lumberjack"
}
}
output {
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
2. cat logstash-forwarder.conf
{
"network": {
"servers": [ "54.227.XXX.XXX:6782" ],
"ssl ca": "/etc/logstash-forwarder/server.crt",
"ssl key": "/etc/logstash-forwarder/server.key",
"timeout": 15`enter code here`
},
"files": [
{
"paths": [
"/opt/logs/L/*.log"
]
```

**Output for logstash**

sudo bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/central.conf
Using milestone 1 input plugin 'lumberjack'. This plugin should work, but would benefit from use by folks like you. Please let us know if you find bugs or have suggestions on how to improve this plugin.  For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}

**Output for Logstash-forwarder**

ubuntu@ip-10-231-15-32:~$ /opt/lumberjack/bin/lumberjack -config /etc/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder.conf

```
-fro                                                                                m-beginning=true
2015/01/13 12:55:09 publisher init
2015/01/13 12:55:09 {
"network": {
"servers": [ "54.227.XXX.XXX:6782" ],
"ssl ca": "/etc/logstash-forwarder/server.crt",
"ssl key": "/etc/logstash-forwarder/server.key",
"timeout": 15
},
"files": [
{
"paths": [
"/opt/logs/L/*.log"
]
}
]
}

2015/01/13 12:55:09.498742 Setting trusted CA from file: /etc/logstash-forwarder/server.crt
2015/01/13 12:55:09.499091 Connecting to 54.227.XXX.XXX:6782
2015/01/13 12:55:09.566860 Connected to 54.227.XXX.XXX:6782
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

logstash-forwarder should log files it has found before network connection. Please recheck file and directory permissions that user running logstash-forwarder can do

```
ls /opt/logs/L/*.log
```

and

```
cat /opt/logs/L/*.log
```

Comment: Thanks.I checked the permission and changed it, but yet I'm seeing this2015/01/13 14:08:03.735553 Skipping old file: /opt/logs/mc.L27.log
2015/01/13 14:08:03.735668 Setting trusted CA from file: /etc/logstash-forwarder/server.crt
2015/01/13 14:08:03.736010 Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:6782
2015/01/13 14:08:04.255147 Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6782

Comment: By default logstash-forwarder seems to skip files which have no activity for 24 hours.

Comment: Ok it's skipping for 24 hrs then what is the solution to overcome it if I need to check for parse the old logfiles

Comment: I have not tested but you coul try to run   touch /opt/logs/mc.L27.log   to update file timestamp.

Comment: FYI I first tried with timestamp then only renamed the file like mc.L27.log

Comment: OK. Logstash-forwarder remembers the files it has checked and where it is in each file. But now you got new fresh file. Glad you had it working.